# Limit of a hyperbolic trig function inside a square root

Tags: calculus, limits

I am asked to find this limit here:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2}}{x+1}-x$$

I combined the terms to get

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2}-x(x+1)}{x+1}$$

But if I try and factor out terms, I get

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2\sqrt{1+\frac{\tanh(x)}{x}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}}-x^2(1+\frac{1}{x})}{x(1+\frac{1}{x})}$$

and that won't cancel with the x which I have on the bottom so the limit just blows up. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

The limit is apparently $\frac{-1}{2}$ but i'm not sure how that's the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit cannot be found in your way.

Multiplying $$\frac{\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2}-x(x+1)}{x+1}$$
by
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2}+x(x+1)}{\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2}+x(x+1)}\ (=1)$$
gives
$$\frac{(x^4+x^3\tanh(x)+x^2)-(x^2+x)^2}{(x+1)(\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2}+x(x+1))}$$
$$=\frac{x^3(\tanh(x)-2)}{(x+1)(\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2}+x(x+1))}$$
$$=\frac{\tanh(x)-2}{(1+\frac 1x)\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{\tanh(x)}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1+\frac 1x\right)}\to -\frac 12$$
as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Oh my gosh! I forgot all about the conjugate! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2}}{x+1}-x$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2}-x(x+1)}{x+1}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2-x^2(x+1)^2}{(x+1)(\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2}+x(x+1))}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2-x^2(x^2+2x+1)}{(x+1)(\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2}+x(x+1))}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2-x^4-2x^3-x^2}{(x+1)(\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2}+x(x+1))}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{3}\tanh(x)-2x^3}{(x+1)(\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2}+x(x+1))}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{3}\tanh(x)-2x^3}{(x+1)\left(x^2\sqrt{1+\frac  {\tanh(x)}x+\frac 1 {x^2}}+x^2+x\right)}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{3}\tanh(x)-2x^3}{\left(x^3\sqrt{1+\frac  {\tanh(x)}x+\frac 1 {x^2}}+x^3+x^2\right)+\left(x^2\sqrt{1+\frac  {\tanh(x)}x+\frac 1 {x^2}}+x^2+x\right)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\tanh(x)-2}{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac  {\tanh(x)}x+\frac 1 {x^2}}+1+\frac 1 x\right)+\left(\frac 1 x\sqrt{1+\frac  {\tanh(x)}x+\frac 1 {x^2}}+\frac 1 x+ \frac 1 {x^2}\right)} = -\frac 1 2$$

Comment: I think in the very last step, for the second term in the denominator, there should be a 1 and not 1/x. Otherwise I like this a lot.

Comment: Actually no that's right never mind. But if I take the limit to infinity of that term, I get a 0 don't I?

Comment: It seems that you did $(x+1)A=xA\color{red}{\times }A$ from 7th to 8th in the denominators.

Comment: Right. An x could just be factored from the first term and a square term from the other stuff to cancel with the numerator.

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty i fixed that

Answer (score 0):

*I do not knwo how much this is valid or not.*

When $x\to\infty$, $\tanh(x)\to 1$. So, it seems to me that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}\tanh(x)+x^2}}{x+1}-x=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}+x^2}}{x+1}-x$$ Now, $$\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}+x^2}=x^2\sqrt{1+\frac 1x+\frac 1 {x^2}}$$ Now, using $$\sqrt{1+\epsilon}=1+\frac{\epsilon }{2}-\frac{\epsilon ^2}{8}+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$ and replacing $\epsilon$ by $\left(\frac 1x+\frac 1 {x^2}\right)$, $$\sqrt{1+\frac 1x+\frac 1 {x^2}}=1+\frac{1}{2 x}+\frac{3}{8 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$ $$\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}+x^2}=x^2\sqrt{1+\frac 1x+\frac 1 {x^2}}=x^2+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3}{8}+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ Now, using long division to get $$\frac{\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}+x^2}}{x+1}=x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{7}{8 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ $$\frac{\sqrt{x^4+x^{3}+x^2}}{x+1}-x=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{7}{8 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ Using $x=10$, the "exact" value is $\approx -0.422133$ while the above asymptotics gives $-\frac{33}{80}=-0.4125$